# How to integrate google location autocomplete for ios 7

Tags: ios7, autocomplete, storyboard

am unable to integrate SPGoogleplacesautocomplete in my app ios 7 storyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlast I found on the GITHUB

But On Scroll view it will work for iphone5 slight problem with iphone4

https://github.com/StephenAsherson/SAGooglePlacesTableView